# JS function only returns undefined but alert outputs correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a Javascript function that is obtaining the first and last name from a PHP file then returning the value. When this Alerts it does produce the correct value but after return and calling this variable it produces undefined:

```
function getname(username){
  var output="";

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getusername.php?username='+username,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
      output += data;
      alert(output);
      return output;
    }
  });
}
```

So the alert(output) above produces the name: "John Doe" in an alert. Now when I come to call this function in another function:

```
var username = 'jdoe';
var uname='';
uname += getname(username);
alert("Username: "+username+"\nName: "+uname)
```

This will output Username: jdoe Name: undefined. I have tried multiple ways of doing this but it just seems that the value being returned is undefined when it actually outputs correctly on the alert.

I have tried to define the variables as strings then add the values on thereafter but no luck, what am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: you need to use a callback function passed to `getname` since `$.ajax` is asynchronous

Comment: [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getname(username){
  var output="";

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getusername.php?username='+username,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
      output += data;
      alert(output);
    }
  });
  return output;
}
```

However, above version should work. 
Still here is **Callback version:**

```
function getname(username, callback){
  var output="";

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getusername.php?username='+username,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
      output += data;
      alert(output);
      callback(output);
    }
  });
}

Call gename() as:
getname(your_user_name, function(output){   // this output refers to the value output
  console.log(output);                      // sent from above line callback(output).
})
```

Comment: Coming back blank unfortunately. How do callback's work?

Comment: Colum Kelly: Updated response with callback version.

Comment: I'd suggest to use promise and not the callback or else the simple AJAX will become very specific to particular functionality.

Comment: Column Kelly: I have never used 'promise' feature since I always found solution using 'async: false'. Have try with 'promise'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your ajax synchronous, you can do something like this:

try this:

```
var username = 'jdoe';
getname(username).done(function(data) {
   uname += data;
   alert("Username: "+username+"\nName: "+uname)
}

function getname(username) {
    return $.ajax({
       url: 'getusername.php?username='+username
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. If you want to return the data, either make the call synchronous by passing `async: false` or return the AJAX promise to the calling function which will resolve the value.

So this will work

```
function getname(username){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'getusername.php?username='+username,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text"
    });
}

function callingFunction() {
    var name = getname(username);
    name.done(function(data) {
        /* Perform your operation with the data */
    });
}
```